# Excel - create a list from each cell of a sheet range

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a bunch of sheets in my workbook, in each one there is an email address at B6.

What I want to do is to make a list with all the email addresses. I'm familiar with sheet range (all my sheets are between a sheet "first" and a sheet "last"), so I can do something like `first:last!B6` to refer to the range. But what is the formula?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method 1: Create a list of sheet names and use the `INDIRECT` function. [Here](http://www.contextures.com/xlFunctions05.html#RefSheet) is an example.

Method 2: Use a User Defined Function to reference the sheets by index. [Here](http://j-walk.com/ss/excel/tips/tip63.htm) is a function that should suit you.

Comment: Thanks Neal; I'll go for method 1, since I'm on mac (no VBA). How can I get the sheet names automatically?

Comment: This will give you the sheet name.  This only works if the file is not a temporary excel file (has an actual save location): `=MID(CELL("filename",E6),1+FIND("]",CELL("filename",E6)),100)`